# How to work with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm back-end developer starting with front-end development. I've chosen angular2 for my application and I would like to use bootstrap with it.

As far as I know, using bootstrap is just putting right html classes on right html elements.

Should I put classes directly in my template? Or maybe I should group them somehow in application-specific classes and use only them in html? (So my html file would not be bootstrap specific. But CSS doesn't allow class inheritance, so I don't know if it is even possible).

Later, if I would like to modify something(colors, size, whatever), should I modify bootstrap sources or I can just attach my .css file to the html ?

Is using less or some other css-preprocessors connected to using bootstrap? I mean, is it possible to create custom looking application with bootstrap with just vanilla css?

Comment: How much experience do you have with HTML/CSS?

Comment: Almost none with "production" projects. I know  the syntax and some basics from w3 school tutorials(that I've read few years ago).

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is about putting right classes. Yes put classes directly in your html template. Its not the best practice to alter bootstrap source but you can. Reference bootstrap but also have your own style.css where you have your own styles. Bootstrap is just a baseline, you need to have your own styles to not make it look bootstrappy. Bootstrap uses less preprocessor, everything is less. You can choose to use only those less files you want. Yes it is possible to make custom applications. Don't overload yourself too much, just dig in mate.

Comment: @Krever It seems like you have no experience at all with HTML and CSS. You might want to brush up on the basics. Then you can move onto Bootstrap and LESS or SCSS.

Comment: @Jyeon, I think html(and css maybe too) has nothing that can hurt me, so my rusty theoretical knowledge is enough to go with angular2 tutorial. But then I wanted to add some pretty styling and here comes my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it is possible to "extend" bootstrap css classes, maybe not with normal css classes, but css pre-processors (like LESS, which you mentioned) have the ability to create mixins that rely on existent styles. try that out.
   though, there is nothing wrong with using bootstrap classes directly
2. if you want your styles to work a little different then how bootstrap usually does, do not change the bootstrap sources, but override the classes with your own css (there are a few exceptions, though, but only case specific).
3. using css-preprocessors (such as LESS or SASS) with bootstrap is well supported, there are even some libraries/projects related to it which you can easily find (here's an [example](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial)).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I put classes directly in my template?

Yes you should. As you mention CSS classes do not support any kind of inheritance so the concept to create an abstraction layer is not feasible. Also, If you need to switch to a different CSS framework you will need to change the HTML also.

> Should I modify bootstrap sources or I can just attach my .css file to the html ?

Bootstrap provides a [customizing tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to override some of its default values so you could use that. Also, you can save your configuration to a JSON file and keep it for future reference.

For additional changes you should have a new CSS file to add new styles and override existing ones.

> Is using less or some other css-preprocessors connected to using bootstrap?

CSS preprocessors output regular (vanilla) CSS. So, yes, it is possible to create Bootstrap-like applications with CSS only. Preprocessors will help you to have your CSS more easily maintainable.